# How to keep an absolute fluid div width fixed regardless the body width

Tags: html, css

I have a 'fluid div that grows horizontally auto with its content.
It is placed absolutely on body. 
My problem is that if you decrease the window width, the div decrease itself.

You can play with the snippet code, placing the div near the right border or decreasing the width of window. As you can see the div width is limited to the right border and the content is re-located vertically.

I can't specify a fixed width because I dont know the content of div.

I have a body overflow:hidden (I dont want scrollbars)

I have played with a lot of css attributes without success. 
Any help would be appreciated

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 500px; top: 100px;  background-color: rgb(165, 115, 98);padding: 5px">

  <span>Hello</span><input type="button"  value="...">
  <span>Hello</span><input type="button"  value="...">
  <span>Hello</span><input type="button"  value="...">
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

help?

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 500px; top: 100px;  background-color: rgb(165, 115, 98);padding: 5px;white-space:nowrap;">

  <span>Hello</span><input type="button"  value="...">
  <span>Hello</span><input type="button"  value="...">
  <span>Hello</span><input type="button"  value="...">
  
  </div>
```

Comment: How do i add this blue color code snippet in my code? I don't know how to add this.

Comment: @GopsAB, in answer panel click *Ctrl + M* or hit the "Code snippet" button.

Comment: @matewka. Your code works fine but it seems that float attribute pollutes the schema. Please give left-floated  to the three spans and you can see that the main div has no right width... What ? Any way to fix this ? I have a lot of floated content I want to insert in that div....

Comment: @tonnot, what you're facing here is the typical floating problem. You need to add the _clearfix_ to the parent div. Simply, after all `span` elements add such element: `<div style="clear: both"></div>`

Comment: @matewka Sorry but the clearfix does nothing. White-space does not work if elements has float value. You can try it...

Answer (score 0):

```
    .yourParentDiv
    {
       //Remove left
       float: right;
       position: relative;
    }
```

It solves your problem

```css
div
{
  float: right;
 
  }
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; top: 100px;  background-color: rgb(165, 115, 98);padding: 5px">

  <span>Hello</span><input type="button"  value="...">
  <span>Hello</span><input type="button"  value="...">
  <span>Hello</span><input type="button"  value="...">
  
  </div>
```